# Wrapper is not centered

Tags: css

At a certain width the wrapper should shrink and become centered like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SioTF.jpg but for some reason it doesn't work for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8oA4.jpg What am I doing wrong ? 
CSS:

```
div#header {
    height: 140px !important;
    width: 940px !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 30px;
    width: 803px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h1 {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 35px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 269px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_logo.png') no-repeat !important;
    float: left !important;
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h1 a {
    display: block !important;
    width: 269px !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    text-indent: -9999px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a.nl {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo.png') no-repeat !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 200px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a.nl:hover {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo_hover.png') no-repeat !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a.en {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo_en.png') no-repeat !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 200px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a.en:hover {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo_hover_en.png') no-repeat !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a.fr {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo_fr.png') no-repeat !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 200px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a.fr:hover {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo_hover_fr.png') no-repeat !important;
}

div#header_logo h2 a {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 30px !important;
    right: 120px !important;
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo.png') no-repeat !important;
    float: right !important;
    margin-left: 200px !important;
}

div#header div#header_logo h2 a:hover {
    height: 75px !important;
    width: 334px !important;
    text-indent: -5000px !important;
    background: url('../images/compudoc_side_logo_hover.png') no-repeat !important;
}

.hiding span {
    display: none;
}

.search {
    position: relative;
    left: 710px;
    bottom: 161px;
}

.search input {
    width: auto !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

.search input:focus {
    background-color: #f1f6ff !important;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid #cad3cb;
    padding: 20px;
}

.item img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}

div#languageChoice {
    width: 70px !important;
    float: right !important;
}

div#languageChoice img {
    display: inline-block !important;
    width: 15px !important;
    height: 12px !important;
    margin-right: 4px !important;
}

#logo {
    margin-top: 22px !important;
}

#logo a img {
    float: left !important;
}

#tagline {
    color: #888 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #e9e9e9 !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px !important;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 20px !important;
    float: left !important;
}

div#sitenav {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 40px !important;
    right: 45px !important;
    background: #303030 !important;
    display: block;
    width: 79.3em !important;
    float: left !important;
    max-height: 52px !important;
    margin: 0 29px 15px 0;
}

.sitenav2 {
    margin-top: 12px !important;
}

.sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(2) a {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(3), .sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(4), .sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(5), .sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(6), .sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(7), .sitenav2 ul li:nth-child(8) {
    background: url(../css/images/navigation-divider.png) no-repeat right 50%;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
}

div#sitenav ul,
div#sitenav li {
    list-style: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    display: inline !important;
}

div#sitenav ul li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    position: relative !important;
}

div#sitenav ul li a {
    display: inline-block !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    padding: 17px 20px !important;
}

div#sitenav ul li a:hover {
    background: #2db2ea !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(1) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(2) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(3) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(4) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(5) a, div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(6) a {
    background: url(../css/images/navigation-divider.png) no-repeat right 50%;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(1) a {
    margin-left: 50px !important;
}

div#sitenav ul:first-child li:nth-child(2) a {
    background: none;
}

div#sitenav ul:nth-child(3) li a {
    background-color: #4ea09c;
}

.active {
    background: #2db2ea !important;
}

.submenu-active {
    color: #2db2ea !important;
}

/*here*/
#content_container {
    position: relative !important;
    /*width: 960px !important;*/
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#pageContent {
    float: left !important;
    width: 780px;
}

#pageContent h2 {
    font-weight: normal !important;
    padding: 11px 0 0 0 !important;
}

#pageContent a {
    color: #2db2ea;
}

#pageContent a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#pageContent p {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}

#pageContent ul {
    list-style: disc inside !important;
}

.pageContentShop {
    width: 780px !important;
}

.details a {
    font-size: 1px !important;
}

.ui-dialog {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 446px !important;
}

.thumb small a {
    color: #666666 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    cursor: default !important;
}

#bolded-line {
    background: #2db2ea !important;
}

p {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

img.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    display: none;
}

/*Table*/
.table, table.admin, table.factuur, table.lid_detail, table.klant {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
}

.table th, table.admin th, table.factuur th, table.lid_detail th, table.klant th {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #404040;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.table td:last-child, table.admin td:last-child, table.factuur td:last-child, table.lid_detail td:last-child, table.klant td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table th:last-child, table.admin th:last-child, table.factuur th:last-child, table.lid_detail th:last-child, table.klant th:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table td, table.admin td, table.factuur td, table.lid_detail td, table.klant td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: #e0e0e0 1px solid;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.table tr:hover td, table.admin tr:hover td, table.factuur tr:hover td, table.lid_detail tr:hover td, table.klant tr:hover td {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

.tableFacturen th, .tableFacturen td {
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.tableMijn th, .tableMijn td {
    padding: 2px !important;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.no-padding-1 th, .no-padding-1 td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px !important;
}

table.lid_detail tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0 !important;
}

table.lid_detail input[type="submit"] {
    margin-right: 25px !important;
}

.borderTop tr:first-of-type td {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0 !important;
}

/**/

img.report_problem {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content_container #sec_nav_container, #sec_nav_container2,
#content_container .columns {
    float: left !important;
    display: inline !important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#sec_nav_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 805px;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

#sec_nav_container2 {
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    right: 17px;
    padding-right: 11px;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

#sec_nav_container {
    width: 160px !important;
}

#sec_nav_container img:first-child {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

#topVerkoop .tabel img {
    width: 130px !important;
    height: 90px !important;
}

.tabel_hoofding small {
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.no-border td {
    border: none !important;
}

.no-border-2 {
    border: none !important;
}

.add tbody input {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.tabel {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}

table.formPadding td {
    padding-right: 12px !important;
}

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
#content_container:after {
    content: "\0020" !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    clear: both !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

#submenu li a {
    color: #666;
    display: block !important;
    padding: 3px 0 !important;
    padding-left: 12px !important;
    background: url(../css/images/links-list-arrow-02.png) no-repeat left 47% !important;
}

.links-list li a:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
}

#submenu li a:hover {
    color: #2db2ea;
}

.links-list li:first-child a,
#submenu li:first-child a {
    margin: -3px 0 0 0 !important;
}

div#comment_ticker h4 {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 16px !important;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
textarea,
select {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.notification {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 14px 40px 14px 18px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.1);
    background-color: #ffe9e9;
    color: #de5959 !important;
    border: 1px solid #fbc4c4;
}

.notification:before {
    content: "Error: ";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.notification a {
    color: #de5959 !important;
}

.notification a:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.ui-dialog {
    top: 100px !important;
    position: fixed !important;
}

/*code for the carousel */
#carousel_inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 950px; /* important (this width = width of list item(including margin) * items shown */
    overflow: hidden; /* important (hide the items outside the div) */
    /* non-important styling bellow */
    /*background: #ffffff;*/
}

#carousel_ul {
    position: relative;
    left: -150px; /* important (this should be negative number of list items width(including margin) */
    list-style-type: none; /* removing the default styling for unordered list items */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 9999px; /* important */
    /* non-important styling bellow */
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#carousel_ul li {
    float: left; /*important for inline positioning of the list items*/
    width: 180px; /*fixed width, important*/
    /* just styling bellow*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    /*height:40px;*/
    color: #fff;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    /*background: #ffffff;*/
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: default;
}

#carousel_ul li center a img {
. margin-bottom : - 4 px; /* IE is making a 4px gap bellow an image inside of an anchor (<a href...>) so this is to fix that */
    /* styling */
    cursor: hand;
    border: 0px;
}

#left_scroll, #right_scroll {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#left_scroll img, #right_scroll img {
    border: 0; /* remove the default border of linked image */
    /*styling*/
    cursor: hand;

}

.form-margin {
    margin-right: 3px !important;
}

#footer-bottom {
    cursor: default;
    height: 20px !important;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer-bottom a:hover {
    color: #2db2ea !important;
}

#footer-bottom-shop {
    padding: 22px 0;
    cursor: default;
    height: 7px !important;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer-bottom-shop a {
    color: #fff;
}

.shop-footer-text {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 13px !important;
}

#footer-bottom-shop a:hover {
    color: #2db2ea !important;
}

#scroll-top-top {
    width: 35px;
    position: relative;
    left: 925px;
    bottom: 40px;
}

#scroll-top-top a {
    background-color: #2db2ea;
}

.scroll-top-top-shop {
    bottom: 39px !important;
}

#save {
    cursor: hand;
}

td.item:hover {
    background: #fafafa;
}

.loginForm {
    margin: 0 180px;
}

.login {
    margin: 0;
}

input[type="submit"], #pageContent input[type="button"] {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
    background: #444 !important;
    padding: 9px 12px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    width: auto !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out !important;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover, #pageContent input[type="button"]:hover {
    background: #2db2ea !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

#pageContent input[type="button"] {
    margin-right: 4px !important;
}

#pageContent form small {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

#pageContent form td {
    padding-right: 8px !important;
}

#pageContent select {
    padding: 5px 8px !important;
}

#pageContent form input[type="text"], #pageContent form input[type="username"], #pageContent form input[type="password"], #pageContent select, #pageContent textarea, #pageContent select.form-margin {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1029px) {

    #sitenav {
        display: none !important;
    }

    #wrapper {
        margin: 15px auto !important;
        padding: 25px 70px !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        background: #fff;
    }

    /*#header, #main_container {*/
    /*width: 768px !important;*/
    /*}*/
    #pageContent {
        width: 110%;
    }

    #footer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 15px 0 0 0;
        width: 100% !important;
    }

}

/*@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {*/

/*div#sitenav {*/
/*float: none !important;*/
/*display: none !important;*/
/*}*/

/*.js #nav {*/
/*display: none !important;*/
/*}*/
/*}*/
```

Comment: You need to work on narrowing down the issue. And post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need `display: block` on elements that have `margin: 0 auto` if you want them centered...

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 15px auto !important;
    padding: 25px 70px !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: You mentioned wrapper and you mentioned it not being centered, so my code addresses that, but your images show something entirely different. So are you sure the wrapper not being centered is your issue? Without posting any relevant code we're kinda just guessing here.

Comment: It seems that the whole page overflows

Comment: Do you have a link to the active page...where your images came from? It would be a lot easier to diagnose from there then trying to read this wall of code.

Comment: It's all spaghetti. What I can do is show you the html code as how Chrome makes it: http://pastebin.com/Z08r2wvf